# How to Javascript change Label value from selecting Checkbox and drop-down list

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, checkbox, textbox, onchange

I have 2 checkboxes and one of it contains a drop-down list with 5 elements.

- Checkbox A
- Checkbox B: drop-down list
- Textbox

First have to check if the checbox B is checked, then Textbox only can be showing value, otherwise is empty.
Secondly, if checkbox B checked and a value from drop-down list been selected, then the Textbox must show value immidiately on the changes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="events" value="event02 />
Event 01
</input>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="events" value="event02 />
Event 02:
<select name="selectOne" onchange="amount()">
    <option value="00" selected="selected">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="displayTxtBox" id="displayTxtBox" size="10" maxlength="50" value="" />
```

I have no idea in Javascript how to write code detect the Checkbox B detected and Drop-down List selected only display value on Textbox.

I think it needs onChange and some function in Javascript.

Please kindly guide me.

Comment: `input` elements can't contain other elements, so they don't have a closing `</input>` tag: So your *first* `input` is invalid HTML, which means the browser attempts automatic error-recovery with unpredictable results. Please unwrap that text, remove the closing tag, and use a self-closing tag instead (as you have with the other `input` elements. Also, your second `input` tag has an unclosed string (for the `value` attribute).

Answer (score 1):

Given corrected HTML, with added `id` attributes and `label` elements to provide additional click-targets for the various form elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="input1" name="events" value="event01" />
<label for="input1">Event 01</label>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="input2" name="events" value="event02" />
<label for="input2">Event 02</label>

<select name="selectOne">
    <option value="00" selected="selected">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="displayTxtBox" id="displayTxtBox" size="10" maxlength="50" value="" />​
```

The following JavaScript seems to work for your intended results, though I wasn't entirely certain of your intent:

```
function showAmount(el, selectEl, targetEl, clearOnUncheck) {
    /* the following is an optional, Boolean, variable, so a ternary
       conditional is used, which checks that 'clearOnUncheck' exists, 
       if it does then the variable is assigned its own value,
       if *not* then it's explicitly assigned the value of false
       note it's Boolean, *not* a string: don't quote this value */
    var clearOnUncheck = clearOnUncheck ? clearOnUncheck : false;
    if (!el || !selectEl || !targetEl) {
        // sanity checking, these are *required* arguments for the function
        return false;
    }
    // if the checkbox is checked, continue
    else if (el.checked) {
        /* assigning the conditions I'm testing to variables, so if conditions
           change they only have to be changed in one place */
        var index = selectEl.selectedIndex,
            textcontent = (typeof(el.textContent) != 'undefined');
        if (textcontent) {
            // up-to-date browsers
               /* sets the value of the text-input to be the string contained
                  within the selected option from the select element */
            targetEl.value = selectEl
                .getElementsByTagName('option')[index]
                .textContent;
        }
        else if (window.innerText) {
            // IE < 8
               // as above, but uses innerText for IE
            targetEl.value = selectEl
                .getElementsByTagName('option')[index]
                .innerText;
        }
    }
    /* if the checkbox is unchecked, and you've set the Boolean for the
       optional clearOnUncheck to true (remember, *not* a string, don't quote) */
    else if (!el.checked && clearOnUncheck) {
        /* if clearOnUncheck is true, the value is cleared from the text-input,
           if clearOnUncheck is set to false, or not-set, the text-box value
           persists after unchecking the checkbox */
        targetEl.value = '';
    }
}

// references to the elements
var input2 = document.getElementById('input2'),
    select = document.getElementsByName('selectOne')[0],
    textInput = document.getElementById('displayTxtBox');

// binding the function to the onchange event of the input2 and selectOne elements.
input2.onchange = function() {
    showAmount(input2, select, textInput, true);
};
select.onchange = function() {
    /* because the clearOnUncheck argument depends on the changing of the
       checkbox there's no point in passing it to the showAmount() function
       in the select's onchange event-handler */
    showAmount(input2, select, textInput);
};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo with `clearOnUncheck == true`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TcMnv/)

[JS Fiddle demo with `clearOnUncheck == false`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TcMnv/1/)

[JS Fiddle demo with `clearOnUncheck` not set](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TcMnv/2/)

References:

- [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/checked).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent).
- [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/selectedIndex).
- [Ternary/conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).